# Are the human cerebral hemispheres only connected via the corpus callosum?

Tags: neuroscience, neuroanatomy

Are the human cerebral hemispheres only connected via the *corpus callosum*? Or is there any other structure for interaction between the left and right hemispheres?

Answer (score 7):

The *corpus callosum* is a massive horizontal white matter tract (commissure) that connects the two hemispheres and it is considered the most important route of communication between the hemispheres.

However, there are [five additional commissures](http://radiopaedia.org/articles/commissures-of-the-brain) that cross the midline, namely:

1. [Anterior commissure](http://www.anatomyatlases.org/MicroscopicAnatomy/Section17/Plate17344.shtml), connecting the two olfactory bulbs and the temporal cortices;
2. [Hippocampal commissure](https://www.msu.edu/user/brains/brains/sheep/glossary/hippocampalcommissure.html) (psalterium), connecting the two hippocampal formations;
3. [Habenular commissure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habenular_commissure), connecting the habenular nuclei;
4. [Posterior commissure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_commissure), connecting the pretectal nuclei, mediating the consensual pupillary light reflex;
5. Supraoptic commissures (a. [Gudden's commissure, or ventral supraoptic decussation connecting the medial geniculate bodies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ventral_supraoptic_decussation) and b. [Meynert's commissure](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0006899375903224), connecting the two suprachiasmatic nuclei<sup>*</sup>).

Below figure shows the corpus callosum and the anterios commissure:

[image: anterior commissure]
<sup>Saggital section through the human brain showing the *corpus callosum* and *anterior commissure*. Source: [Brain Atlas](http://www.anatomyatlases.org/MicroscopicAnatomy/Section17/Plate17344.shtml).</sup>

<sup>*The exact connection of Meynert's commissure I am unsure of. This is the best I could do.</sup>

Comment: Actually there are five commissures, not only one. But then the hemispheres are also indirectly connected through their connections with the non-telencephalic parts of the brain.

Comment: @what - 5?! I didn't know that. The brain indeed connects via the pons etc, but those connections are generally considered to carry vertical tracts, not horizontal ones.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commissure // "vertical": yes, but since I don't know what Max has in mind, I thought I'd mention these, since they do carry effects from one hemisphere to the other and so allow "interaction" (as specified in the question).

Comment: @what - how about this edit? Thanks for your comment! Great.